# How to write a homogeneous multivariate polynomial in compact form?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, abstract-algebra

If $f:A\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is in $C^{n+1}(A)$ with $A$ open then fixed $x_0\in A$ $$f(x_0+h) = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\sum(D_{i_1\dots i_k}f)(x_0)h_{i_1}\cdots h_{i_k} + \operatorname{o}(|h|^n)$$ where the inner sum has $n^k$ terms, one for each partial derivative of order $k$. Playing with this inner sum I noticed that the $k$th term is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $k$ in $\mathbb{R}[h_1,\dots,h_n]$. Looking for a compact algebraic form for the generic term I observed that for:

- $k=0$ it's $f(x_0)$, a nice number
- $k=1$ it's $\sum(D_{i_1}f)(x_0)h_{i_1}$, the dot product of the vector $[(D_1f)(x_0),\dots, (D_nf)(x_0)]$ with $h$
- $k=2$ it's $\sum(D_{i_1i_2}f)(x_0)h_{i_1}h_{i_2}$, the scalar product of $h$ with itself respect to the product defined by the matrix $[(D_jf_i)(x_0)]_{ij}$

Are there some algebraic objects/operations to accomplish this for $k=n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. A homogeneous polynomial function of degree $d$ on a vector space $V$ is just an element of the [symmetric power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra) $S^d(V^{\ast})$. You can represent these things, if you really want to, using [symmetric tensors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor). For $d = 1$ this just gives an element of $V^{\ast}$, for $d = 2$ this gives a "matrix" (although it is somewhat dangerous IMO to think in these terms because one is making two choices), and so forth.